# With <form> <textarea> how to create a linebreak when user presses enter

Tags: html, forms, textarea

I have a textarea in a form which then outputs the users written text in the style of a question and answer forum.

However, when the user presses ENTER for what they see as a new line withing this textarea when the text is submitted and then appears on the screen the string is all in one long line with no linebreaks visible.

How can I rectify this problem?

As you can see here, within this textarea I have created new lines by pressing ENTER and I want the exact same thing to happen on my site.

Comment: You need to use the server side language of your choice to turn new lines in `<br>`

Comment: Ah okay, is there no way to do it then via using HTML or CSS?

Answer (score 0):

A new line in a textarea is a new line character.

If you output that to an HTML document, it will be treated like any other new line character (i.e. as collapsable white space).

You need to express the new line in HTML terms.

- Wrap the content in a `<pre>` element.
- Use the CSS white-space property
- Process the text to replace new lines with paragraph and/or line break markup

Note that outputting user input to the browser without suitable processing will render you vulnerable to XSS attacks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the special simbol "\r" with tag br.

c#:

```
yourtext.Replace("\r", "<br>");
```